# Which row will be evaluated when using HAVING clause to a candidate group?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm new to SQL. Today I am using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clause to a table, just like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tab(a, b);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES(0, 1);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES(-1, 1);

SELECT COUNT(b) FROM tab GROUP BY b HAVING a;
```

I got nothing output.

But when I changed the order of the two `INSERT` statements, I got the output `2`.

So I got two distinct output just by changing the order of two `INSERT` statements.

The candidate group may be discarded when the result of evaluating the HAVING clause is false, but which column does SQLite use to evaluate the value for the HAVING clasuse?

I wonder if this behavior is specified in the SQL standard or in the SQLite documentation.

Comment: In most databases, you would get an error because `a` is not defined after the aggregation.  The result is indeterminate, as you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Your code would not even run in most databases because it contains the non-aggregate expression `a` in the `HAVING` clause.
But SQLite allows it.

From [SELECT/Simple Select Processing/Generation of the set of result rows](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#resultset):

> If a HAVING clause is specified, it is evaluated once for each group
> of rows as a boolean expression. If the result of evaluating the
> HAVING clause is false, the group is discarded. If the HAVING clause
> is an aggregate expression, it is evaluated across all rows in the
> group. **If a HAVING clause is a non-aggregate expression, it is
> evaluated with respect to an arbitrarily selected row from the
> group**...

What happens is that SQLite chooses an arbitrary row of the group (usually the first) to evaluate the `HAVING` clause.
This is why you get different results when you change the order of insertion of the rows.